# Trying to make a formula to calculate time in between 2 dateTimes to activate Dark Theme in Flutter

Tags: flutter, math, dart

*This is less of a question on Flutter, more of a Dart and Math question.*

I am trying to make my app theme itself when the user turns on the auto dark theme switch, or when he returns to the app.

I have already set up the option for the user to change the **initial time** and the **end time** of the auto dark theme this gives us **DateTime()** variables which contain data of *year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, etc.* (hours in 24h format)

**For now I have this Formula:**

```
if ((now.hour >= _startTime.hour && now.minute >= _startTime.minute) || (now.hour <= _endTime.hour && now.minute <= _endTime.minute)) {
      setTheme('dark');
} else {
      setTheme('light');
}
```

I thought it worked fine but as you can see in this picture and setting. It didn't work properly...
[image]

These are the variables:

```
_startTime = 1:00 AM = 1
now = 10:40PM = 22:40
_endTime = 8:00 AM = 8
```

by using my formula: `((now.hour >= _startTime.hour && now.minute >= _startTime.minute) || (now.hour <= _endTime.hour && now.minute <= _endTime.minute))` this creates a **True** and a **False** which equates to **True** and activates the Dark Theme.

How can I perfect this formula? it seems easy to do but in reality is very confusing.

## Edit: for those who like to deal with numbers

Let's start with the pickers (widgets that allow the user to input date or time)

```
class HourPickers extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CustomAppThemeProvider themeProvider =
        Provider.of<CustomAppThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    DateTime startTime = themeProvider.getStartTime;
    DateTime endTime = themeProvider.getEndTime;
    print('from provider:\n$startTime & $endTime');
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Switch(
                value: themeProvider.getIsAutoThemeSwitchOn,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
                onChanged: (boolean) {
                  themeProvider.setIsAutoThemeSwitchOn(boolean);
                },
              ),
              Text(
                'Tema Oscuro Automático',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text(
            'Inicio',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                  initialDateTime: DateTime(startTime.year, startTime.month,
                      startTime.day, startTime.hour, startTime.minute),
                  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime pickedTime) {
                    Provider.of<CustomAppThemeProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .setStartTime(pickedTime);
                  },
                  use24hFormat: false,
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Final',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                  initialDateTime: DateTime(endTime.year, endTime.month,
                      endTime.day, endTime.hour, endTime.minute),
                  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime pickedTime) {
                    Provider.of<CustomAppThemeProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .setEndTime(pickedTime);
                  },
                  use24hFormat: false,
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is where the provider goes ( I just took out the theming part)

```
bool get getIsAutoThemeSwitchOn => _isAutoThemeSwitchOn;

  Future<bool> getPrefIsAutoThemeSwitchOn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _prefAutoTheme = prefs.getBool('AutoTheme') ?? false;
    _isAutoThemeSwitchOn = _prefAutoTheme;
    return _prefAutoTheme;
  }

  Future<void> setIsAutoThemeSwitchOn(boolean) async {
    _isAutoThemeSwitchOn = boolean;
    // print(_isAutoThemeSwitchOn);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('AutoTheme', boolean);
    if (boolean == true) {
      autoThemeSetter();
    } else {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  void autoThemeSetter() {
    // only if switch is ON
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    if (_startTime.isAfter(_endTime)) _endTime = _endTime.add(Duration(days: 1));

    print('start: $_startTime');
    print('now: $now');
    print('end: $_endTime');
    print('now >= start? ${now.isAfter(_startTime)}');
    print('now <= end? ${now.isBefore(_endTime)}');

    if (now.isAfter(_startTime) && now.isBefore(_endTime)) {
      // print('auto dark theme');
      setTheme('dark');
    } else {
      // print('auto light theme');
      setTheme('light');
    }
    // had add notify even if switch != true because the switch value needs to update
    notifyListeners();
  }

  getPrefTimes() async {
    await getPrefsStartTime();
    await getPrefsEndTime();
  }

  getPrefsStartTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt('startTime') != null) {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      _startTime =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(prefs.getInt('startTime'));

      print('start pref: $_startTime');

      // set the day equal to now.day
      if (now.day != _startTime.day) {
        _startTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, _startTime.hour, _startTime.minute);
      }
      // sub -1 day if needed
      if (_startTime.isAfter(now)) _startTime = _startTime.subtract(Duration(days: 1));

      // update SharedPref because why not
      // setStartTime(_startTime);
    }
  }

  getPrefsEndTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt('endTime') != null) {
      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      _endTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(prefs.getInt('endTime'));

      print('end pref: $_endTime');

      // set the day equal to now.day
      if (now.day != _endTime.day) {
        _endTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, _endTime.hour, _endTime.minute);
      }
      // add +1 day if needed
      if (_startTime.isAfter(_endTime)) _endTime = _endTime.add(Duration(days: 1));

      // update SharedPref because why not
      // setStartTime(_endTime);
    }
  }

  get getStartTime => _startTime;
  get getEndTime => _endTime;

  Future<void> setStartTime(DateTime pickedTime) async {
    // print(pickedTime);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    _startTime = pickedTime;
    // sub -1 day if needed
      if (_startTime.isAfter(now)) _startTime = _startTime.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
    int epoch = _startTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    prefs.setInt('startTime', epoch);
    // print(prefs.getInt('startTime'));
  }

  Future<void> setEndTime(DateTime pickedTime) async {
    // print(pickedTime);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    _endTime = pickedTime;
    // sub -1 day if needed
      if (_startTime.isAfter(now)) _startTime = _startTime.subtract(Duration(days: 1));
    int epoch = _endTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    prefs.setInt('endTime', epoch);
  }
}
```

you can already see this isn't as easy as it seems, there is a lot in the background for just an auto theme switcher.

btw autoThemeSetter() gets called everytime app resumes from background.

Comment: what do you see if you run: `print('$_startTime < $now < $_endTime');`  ?

Comment: that only prints some the parsed format like this: 2020-03-08 02:00:00.000 < 2020-03-09 01:34:27.707060 < 2020-03-09 08:00:00.000. I think I'm giving up on this project of auto theme. I think I need to included the day also to make this work but it's too much of a hassle, having to subtract and/or add 1 day difference in order to make it work.

Comment: so `DateTime.isAfter / isBefore` methods dont work?

Comment: they do work but the logic is very complex. Because we also have to take into account the date entered is correct and the date when recovered from database is updated. Making this a lot more complicated than it should.

Comment: so you should say at the very beginning that your start and end dates are hard to maintain

Comment: startTime and endTime is mot hard to maintain, well maybe. Usually user selects hour and minutes and that info contains even year and month. which I convert into epoch (int) and save to sharedPreferences. When user resumes app, I convert it back into DateTime and update the datetime because who knows hoe long was the app inactive or unused. THIS is the difficult part. The logic to fix the dates. Another issue I mentioned to another user here is the input of time. If I am at 2am and decide to use darkmode from 8pm to 8am how can flutter know if I meant 8pm from yesterday or today? mking it cplx

Comment: `var start = DateTime.parse('2020-03-08 22:00:00.000');
var end = DateTime.parse('2020-03-09 08:00:00.000');

inBetween(String s) {
  var now = DateTime.parse(s);
  var diff = now.difference(start);
  now = now.subtract(Duration(days: diff.inDays));
  var b = now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end);
  print('$s => $b');
}
inBetween('2020-03-12 21:00:00.000');
inBetween('2021-04-13 03:00:00.000');
inBetween('2022-05-13 09:00:00.000');`

Comment: and? did you try the code i posted? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: sorry, i decided to abandon auto theme because its complex, if you can check, I updated the original code with my current code. The problem with this is the input start and final date from user also needs to be parsed. And updated everytime app starts when on launch or resume. I don't think there is a good solution to this. it's a cat and mouse game. I could be wrong but I don't think there is a formula to fix it all. If I am wrong you can make a simple example to test how you would get the start and end time and also what to do on app resume after a long time without use?

Comment: I gave you a code, did you try it? if so, what's unclear?

Comment: @pskink I think I understand what you are trying to do. Instead of worrying about start and end dates you just modify the now time to fit in between the start and the end right? BUT I think there is still a problem here, how is flutter going to know if when user select start to 2am at 12am, is it 2am from today or yesterday? this is what makes it complicated and unclear, maybe I am not understanding your logic. If so please explain. thanks

Comment: if you see my code I run it with 3different dates, 2 of them were out of night range and one was in the range, if you think that there is a case that does not work, what date/time it is? and yes I shift "now" to the past to run the tests

Comment: your function takes the now time and modifies it to fit the between start and end dates. That is understandable but what if the user changes the start and/or end date? I can see that you can modify the now time just fine but what about the start and end? the user is not going to select the dates, they are only able to select hour and minutes, it's up to us to figure if they mean 2am from today or 2am from yesterday or even 2 am from the future lol. You get what I mean? how are we going to do that? is what I am trying to explain and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula that you are using has some logic flaws.  Mainly, it doesn't check that now is between _startTime and _endTime (the OR should be an AND... but there are still problems)

Just for the sake of explanation, the logic that you are using is, "Make the theme Dark if the current time is after the start time OR if the current time is before the end time"

Let's say current time is 9am, and start time is 1am and end time is 8am. This would set the theme to dark because you used OR, and the 9am is after 1am.  So, it passes since the OR doesn't are about the fact that it's after the endTime.  So, you'd want to use && to check for both, because you want to check that current time is after _startTime AND before _endTime.

Unfortunately, you can't just make it an && and call it a day because the hours and minutes are separate.  So, let's say that the time is 6:01am... and start and end are the same as before. In this case, the first part is true (current time minutes and hours is greater than _startTime minutes and hours, but it would set the theme to LIGHT because current minutes (01) is not less than _endTime minutes, despite the fact that it's clearly in range.

So, one option would be to convert everything to minutes like this:

```
  if ((now.hour * 60 + now.minute) >=
          (_startTime.hour * 60 + _startTime.minute) &&
      ((now.hour * 60 + now.minute) <=
          (_endTime.hour * 60 + _endTime.minute))) {
    print('dark');
  } else {
    print('light');
  }
```

But this has the downside of not checking the date.  for example, it won't work if you wanted to have a start time of 2300 and stop time of 0800.

Another (much better) method would be to use the .isBefore() and .isAfter() methods.  HOWEVER, you need to make sure that they are using the correct date since you're using a DateTime() object.  This might look something like:

```
    var stringDate = DateTime.now().year.toString() + "-" +    DateTime.now().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + "-" + DateTime.now().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0'); 
//I'm assuming that all dates are the same, but you should use the correct dates.

      print(stringDate);
      var now_2 = DateTime.now();

      var _startTime_2 = DateTime.parse(stringDate + " 01:00:00Z");
      var _endTime_2 = DateTime.parse(stringDate+" 08:00:00Z");

      print("now_2="+now_2.toString());
      print("_startTime_2="+_startTime_2.toString());
      print("_endTime_2="+_endTime_2.toString());

        print("inBefore method");
      print("---------------------------------");
      if (_startTime_2.isBefore(now_2) && now_2.isBefore(_endTime_2)) {
        print('dark');
      } else {
        print('light');
      }
```

I made a dartpad file so that you can play with the code here: 
https://dartpad.dev/1f978458eabcaf588c872fa4f6bfdaf0

Comment: Hi @William, we meet again :) thanks for responding. About the logic, I went and gave up on using only hours and minutes but using the entire DateTime() instead. But it is very complicated. As I need to input the time, compare and also retrieve the time while also updating them if required. This process is too much and I don't think will fit on a response like this. But I will try my best to keep a simple example.

Comment: hey!  I didn't realize it was you!  Good to see you again.  And yes.. you really have to use the datetime since you might have the starttime on a different day than the endtime. the second example above does exactly that.

Comment: But the current struggle I have is when user selects a time he usually only has hours and minutes to play with. So lets say that At 2am he decided that he would like to have dark mode activate between 8pm to 8am. Now how will flutter know if user meant 8pm from yesterday OR 8pm from now? The same thing happens to the endTime... which is why I gave up on this project because of it being too complex. @William lets see if you can pull another miracle? ahha

Comment: The logic seems straightforward. (or perhaps I'm missing something?)  You just need to turn it on and off at a set time. So, it would be something like: if currentTime == startTime then set theme to Dark. else if currentTime == endTime then set theme to Light. Because you are expressly given times, you don't really have to worry about the dates.

Comment: You could also add the current status of the theme: if (now > start && theme == light) { theme = dark} else if (now > end && theme == dark) {theme = light)

Comment: in your example, if it's 2am and I turn on the dark/light mode, I wouldn't expect it to immediately go into dark mode.  In my mind, you don't need to worry about the date because you're setting a "time to turn on" and a "time to turn off" and those don't have anything to do with dates, just times. If the user turns off dark mode at 2am, it shouldn't be forced into dark mode...it should just wait until the next time to turn on.

Comment: I updated the post including the backend. You can already see that I had everything working but the input of startTime and endTime were having flaws and honestly my brain can only take so much.

Comment: I just started taking a look at your code.  It's pretty in depth.  I think I'm going to need to take a look at either a working prototype, or your code.  Either way, please open up a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm having very little faith this could work hahaha. I think it would be better if I posted a working version of it later so that everybody can run my code. ok I will accept your answer.

Comment: please forget about this auto theme non sense. this feels more like a cat and mouse game. WHY re-invent the wheel when we already have dark mode on android 10? I'm just gonna add darktheme: Theme.dark() lol. Stupid time and dates.

Comment: hahahaha!! ok. I understand completely. That’s too bad. I always like your questions... they are always interesting!